# Getting specific type of objects from list in java

Tags: java

I have the Object

```
 List<Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
 mylist.add(20);
 mylist.add("Banele");
```

and from mylist i want to only

```
System.out.println("Banele");
```

meaning string not `integer (20).`how can i do this please help me

Comment: Add a condition while iterating list..

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to be creating a `List<Object>`, but you can access each element using the `get` method of the list.

Comment: @Quirliom  True. But his problem is to detect the type after he used `get` :)

Answer (score 3):

Check the object type ,while iterating.

```
 for (Object object : mylist) {
    if(object instanceof  String){
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
for (Object item : myList) {
    if (item instanceof String) {
         // retrieve.
         String myString = (String) item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for (Object object : mylist) {
    if(object instanceof  String){
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the usage of `instanceof`

```
    for (Object object : mylist) {
        if(object.getClass().equals(String.class)){
            System.out.println(object);
        }
    }
```